# Working with CSS, top propery in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change top position of class bbb after 100 ms, but it took out that .css(top) does not work.

Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="ddd"><div class='bbb'>Bobobo</div></div>

</body>
<script>    
  $(function myFunction() {
    setInterval(alertFunc, 100);
  });   

  function alertFunc() {
    var b = $('.bbb').first();
    b.css('top', 100 + 'px');
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what the issue is? It's hard to know what "does not work" mean (it's vague)

Comment: From what I can tell you have the needed syntax.

Comment: You need to have `position: relative` added, otherwise `top` does nothing.

Comment: Why use a `setInterval()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @jhpratt mentioned.  You need to add `position:relative` to the `.bbb` class.

See below.

```js
$(function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(alertFunc, 500);
});

function alertFunc() {
  var b = $('.bbb').first();
  b.css('top', 100 + 'px');
}
```

```css
.bbb {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ddd">
  <div class='bbb'>Bobobo</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()` this way `alertFun()` will only run once.

```js
let alertFunc = function() {

  $('.bbb').css('top', 100 + 'px');

}

setTimeout(alertFunc, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ddd">
  <div class='bbb'>Bobobo</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, if you want to use the top attribute you need to give

```
position:relative;
```

to the element. This way the element will be set relative to his position and this could be a little tricky. By the way i usually prefer to make a container box relative ad put the positionable element absolute in it, so it will be displayed relative to his container:

```
.container{
    position:relative;
}

.element{
    position:absolute;
}
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```